# How do I get the HTML element instead of [object Object] when alerting $(this)

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to see if I've selected the right element with jQuery, using `console.log($(this))` and I get `[object Object]`

Why is that and how do I get the element's name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery objects are alway array's, if you want to have the object itselve, use it as an array, like:

```
console.log($('selector')[0])
```

Get the name:

```
console.log($('selector')[0].name)
console.log($('selector').prop("name"))
```

Get the tagname:

```
console.log( $('#test')[0].tagName );
```

Comment: Thanx, how is it possible, when i use `console.log($(this)[0].tagName);` on click, I get `undefined`??

Comment: You better use `console.log(this.tagName)` or `$(this).prop("tagName")`

Comment: `console.log(this.tagName)` gives me `[object Object]` again

Comment: Please provide some code, I checked on this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/s4Q3q/ and it should be working.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because the `console.log` function expects a text to be logged, and you're passing an *instance*. The function doesn't resolve your instance to its `id`, `name` or any other property by itself. You can pass the `id` or `name` property to the log function tho..

try:

```
console.log($('selector').attr("id"))
```

or

```
console.log($('selector').attr("name"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You get `[object Object]` because that's exactly what it is - a jQuery object.

To get the ID or any other attribute use `attr()`, or for jQuery 1.7+, use `prop()`

```
alert($("#myElement").attr("id"));
alert($("#myElement").attr("name"));

// The same in jQ1.7:
alert($("#myElement").prop("id"));
alert($("#myElement").prop("name"));
```

Answer (score 0):

firebug let you see the structure of objects when you dump them to the console. Eg :

```
console.log($('#logo'))
```

returns :

```
 Object { 0=div#logo, length=1, jquery="1.2.6"}
```

And if I click on it, Firebug brings me to the DOM panel, and I get a "0" with a "plus" on the left that enables you to explore the internal structure of the object.